# iOS: animate a picture spin from an NSThread

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

I'm trying to let a picture spin continuously around it's center. I create a thread which calls  calls a delegate method to update the rotation of the picture. I runs completely through but the rotation doesn't change.
The rotation gets set with

```
 _myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);
```

when I put

```
_myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

into the viewDidLoad-method, the image gets transformed by 90°.
If the code below gets executed, it doesn't do anything, although the hasUpdated-method gets called correctly. The variable newRad contains a valid value.
So what could be the reason that the image won't spin around?
Thanks for any help.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a
    [self setDelegate:self];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (void)hasUpdated:(int)x{
    // Convert Degree to Radian and move the needle

    float newRad =  x * M_PI / 180.0f;
    _myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);

}


- (IBAction)myTest:(id)sender {

    NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myLoop) object:nil];
    [myThread start];
}

- (void) myLoop
{
    int x = 1;
    while(true)
    {


        x++;
        if(x==360)
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        sleep(1);
        [self.delegate hasUpdated:x];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can update UI only in the mainthread.

Comment: I am not sure if this is related to the problem or not, but it should be fixed.  Most of UIKit is not thread safe so you should do [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hasUpdate:) withObject:@(x)] and then change the parameter for hasUpdate to NSNumber.

Comment: Try sticking the _myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad); line within the following block: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ }); to force it to update on the main thread.

Comment: @LyndseyScott That did hit the spot. I thought that because its a delegate method, it still gets run in the main thread. So this means the method hasUpdated runs in the context of "myThread"?

Comment: I guess I'll write my comment out as a proper answer for future question seekers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're attempting to update the UI from the `hasUpdated:` method which has been called from the `myTest:` method which has in turn been called as the selector in the `NSThread` triggered by the `IBAction`, you are in fact attempting to update the UI from this new `NSThread`; but you can only update an app's UI from its *main thread*.

In order to maintain this new thread while still updating the UI during a method within it, you can force the UI to update on the main thread by sticking this line from `hasUpdated:`

```
_myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);
```

into the following block, like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    _myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);

});
```